# Border not surrounding entire div

Tags: html, css

So I have a class called `main` that contains the contents of the entire website. Since I am in the beginning stages of building the website I would like to make sure I have not errors in my code, like missing a closing tag or closing quote, etc. One thing that helps me ensure this, is surrounding my elements with colorful borders.

My main div is suppose to be surrounded by a red border however, the border doesn't surround the entire `div` container which tells me that there is something wrong with my markup. I have been trying to decode this for long time now with no success. I was hoping maybe someone on here could help me troubleshooot this?

http://jsfiddle.net/yvSrB/

Comment: Why not just use the [W3C's HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: Your div with the inline style is the problem.  You've given it a height of 100%.  Your container's height is a fixed value of 1200px.  Therefore this div also has the same height.  However you have another div `#header` that is 134px in height that is causing your div to overflow by 134px.

Comment: The reason seems to be `<div id="main" style="height:1200px;">` - remove the `height`.

Comment: thank you Jrod, it worked. Why does this happen, is the need to clear floats due to markup errors, or just a natural need from time to time?

Comment: There is no need to clear floats here. You'd only need to do that if you had `float: left;` (or right) and wanted some other element to be completely free or "clear" of that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the height for the main div as an inline style:

```
<div id="main" style="width:900px; margin-left:auto; height:1200px; margin-right:auto;">
```

If you want it to expand to fit the contents, remove the height otherwise it will be fixed at 1200px.

Answer (score 2):

Your main div has height 1200px and the content are larger than this width so border is not displaying on the content which are overflowing you can check by increase height it will showed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this doesn't answer your specific question - but in terms of debugging your markup and checking its quality you can use `holmes.css` "The CSS Markup Detective" http://www.red-root.com/sandbox/holmes/  It highlights potential errors and mistakes in your markup.  Include the `holmes.css` file in your development build (or use the bookmarklet tool provided on that link).

Answer (score 0):

Your main div has a height of 1200px... remove this and let the main div expand to whater the containing heights are.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your background colors on your jsfiddle sample, you'll see that your red border wraps underneath the "carousel" div. This is because you've specified a hard-coded height for the "main" div. I don't know if this is because you wanted that to be the minimum height -- in which case you should use `min-height` -- or because you wanted that to be the absolute height. Either way, the box's content has overflowed its container, which is why you can't see the bottom part of the red border.

If you wanted the "main" to have exactly that height and have a scroll bar, add `overflow-y: auto;` to your styling for the "main" div. Otherwise, as I mentioned above, either remove the height declaration entirely or use `min-height: 1200px;` instead to have the "main" div grow to hold your content.